# Device has no access to gateway, but gateway is visibile/pingable

Tags: gateway, pi-hole

I have on my home LAN network my home router set up as gateway and few clients. One client (orangepipc) works also like DNS resolver with installed PiHole. on the gateway(192.168.11.1) is DHCP server, where I have reserved IP address (192.168.11.6) for PiHole. On the gateway is set up this PiHole as Primary DNS resolver and for all the clients in LAN works fine. I am able to ping the PiHole and join there with SSH from the LAN. But If I am join to the Pihole device, from there is not possible join/ping to the gateway or the other device in LAN/WAN. Oh the PiHole device installed only clean actual Armbian, Kodi and PiHole (from the installation script).

The first, what I checked up is gateway set up misconfiguration on PiHole, but I cant see anything wrong. Attaching my settings bellow. Any ideas, pls?

```
ip -4 route | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3
192.168.11.1


ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6e:01:40:a3:84:8e
      inet addr:192.168.11.6  Bcast:192.168.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6c01:40ff:fea3:848e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:324629 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1402480 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:65879699 (65.8 MB)  TX bytes:118278414 (118.2 MB)
      Interrupt:114

ip -4 route
default via 192.168.11.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
192.168.11.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.11.6  metric 100

iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Please, post you complete configuration, the output for the ping test (you are mentioning it) and also a traceroute/mtr output.

Comment: Do `tcpdump -ni eth0` and then `ping 192.168.11.1` (in a different terminal). If you see no outgoing ping packets, the problem is on the PiHole, so next step is `ip route get 192.168.11.1` to verify you've no other rules that interfere. If you see outgoing packets, but no response, the problem is elsewhere, probably on the router.

Comment: Paste the output of `ip route` as well.

Comment: Here is my config (pi hole debug log) https://pastebin.com/HXnL65rp

Comment: I cant do tcpdump, because is not installed and is not possible to download it.

Comment: `ip route` result https://pastebin.com/PjEeLeYn

Comment: `ip route get 192.168.11.1` result https://pastebin.com/UnWbAVZ2

Comment: Armibian config network https://pastebin.com/RZeSsFE8

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all fo you, guys. Incident solved. There was some bug on my home gateway, which disconnected this device after 20 seconds after what i did any changes in home gateway. I did upgrade firmware on my home gateway, did factory reset and set up it again and everything works well.

Thank you all for your time.
Cheers